# how to pass a list to the query in Groovy SQL?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've a scenario to pass a List of char values to the query in Grails.

When I pass the List this is what happening

```
def accounts = ['A', 'B']
 AND acct.account_status_cd  in '${accounts}
```

the query looks like "AND acct.account_status_cd in '[A,B]'"

but it should be  "AND acct.account_status_cd in ('A','B')"

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved it by Passing as a String...

String s = keys.collect { "'$it'" }.join( ',' )

It gives me S = 'A','B','C'

Comment: Just `join()` would suffice in the case where you don't need quoted values in the list (eg. a list of numbers).

Answer (score 3):

A solution could be a NamedQuery inside your domain class, something like this:

```
class Account {

    // code omitted

    static namedQueries = {
       accountsInList { accountList ->
          'in'("account_status_cd", accountList)
       }
}
```

Then you can use this namedQuery like:

```
Account.accountsInList(['A', 'B']).list()
```

Ofcourse you can also use a withCriteria.

See the docs for more info:
http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html